Help me identify a road-trip documentary film set in Ecuador
I remember seeing a beautiful documentary film a few years ago (but no later than 2008); the main character (I think it's a woman, but not sure) is on a road-trip from town to town in Ecuador, using buses, hitchhiking, and so on.
At some point, in a bus, she (?) meets a female student headed for the region's university; also, I seem to remember that there's a mysterious character called Jesus (but an actual man, not the catholic character), who maybe walks along the same road?
Any help in identifying this greatly appreciated, thanks!
